# React Native imports not working after upgrade

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Hi I've been in charge of an old React-Native iOS project and I need to upgrade its React-Native from `0.25.1` to `0.48.0` but I'm running into a lot of compiler issues and can't figure out how to update the code.

I have an `index.ios.js` file that looks like this:

```
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var ResumeIns = require('./resume_ins_controller');
ReactNative.AppRegistry.registerComponent('ResumeInsController', () => ResumeIns.Navigation);
```

A `resume_ins_controller.js` in the root folder that looks like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var EntryManager = require('./entry_manager.js');

class ResumeInsNavigation extends React.Component {
  //....
}
```

and an `entry_manager.js` in the root folder that looks like this:

```
class EntryManager {
  //....
}
module.exports = EntryManager;
```

This code worked OK before the upgrade, but now I get this error:

`Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined`

and the stack trace points to this line:

`module.exports = EntryManager;`

Does anyone know how to get this code working for React-Native 0.48?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's been **a ton** of changes since `0.25.1`. Knowing how painful updates can get, I'd suggest either:

1. **In case of a very complex app:** to update RN version by version with the help of [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tags?after=v0.25.1), and [rn-diff](https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff) if necessary.
2. **In case of a fairly simple app:** to start a new RN project from scratch, and move the app's logic over there.

Either way it would be a good idea to move to ES2015 imports for clarity on named vs default imports as the issue that you're describing is likely caused by the way things are imported, see [v0.25.1 deprecations](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.25.1) + a link to [codemod](https://github.com/sibelius/codemod-RN24-to-RN25) that may help.

Good luck!